# (LUA) Why is this coroutine wrap doesn't seem to work?

Tags: lua, coroutine

My code here:

```lua
coroutine.wrap(function()
    local x = os.clock() + 3
    repeat until os.clock() >= x
    print("Hi")
end)()

print("Bye")
```

Usually, the expected output should be "Bye" and then wait 3 seconds to print "Hi".
However, the coroutine yielded first and printed Hi before Bye.

Did I do something wrong in my code? I am new to coroutines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coroutines are not threads. They do not run simultaneously; only one coroutine inside a thread can run at a time. Once you resume a coroutine (which is what a call to a wrapped coroutine basically does), it runs until it yields control back to the original place which is waiting for a value to be yielded. Since you have no `yield` in the coroutine, it will run to completion when invoked. So your code

- declares an anonymous function
- makes a coroutine wrapper
- resumes the coroutine by invoking the wrapper
- the function runs until `yield`, `return` or end (during the course of which `"Hi"` is printed)
- control returns
- `"Bye"` is printed